# Will Ubuntu phones be root-locked?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have never bought a smart-phone, because they are all root-locked/jailed. It's like buying a car with junk in the back and no key to open the rear door.  Rooting/jail-breaking risks bricking the system and invalidates the guarantee.

So what I want to know is simply this: will Ubuntu phones be root-locked, root-open, or is it a manufacturer decision and nobody yet knows?

Comment: I don't use Ubutu Touch type things *(sort of wish I did, but being me, I would turn the phone into a expensive paperweight)*, but i believe that like a normal Ubuntu install that you can use the sudo command to do stuff - apparently the default password is `phablet` for the root user - see [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2319012)

Answer (score 1):

It will be up to the OEMs and carriers what ships on their phones

Comment: Alas for the sentiment that they are considered 'their' phones.  That, if you'll excuse the pun, is the root of the problem: they are not 'their' phones after poor punters have bought them... manufacturers don't seem to like the concept but the ownership of the property actually changes.

Comment: I share your feelings, but alas they are in fact 'their' phones up until the point they are purchased by a user.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple procedure to make phones rooted.
Especially if they have "pure" linux, not this linux+JAVA mixture (android).
So all the same ;)

My opinion to question :nobody knows

Comment: However easy it is, it still invalidates the warranty.
But as well as that, being able to 'root' a phone is the proof that it's an insecure install to begin with, huh?